# For Python 3.2: Why does adding bytes to a bytes object take longer as more bytes are added?

Tags: python-3.2

I recently started learning Python (my first programming language since using GW BASIC as a kid). I’ve noticed that when adding bytes to a bytes object, each byte takes more time to add than the last; and by contrast, when adding integers to a list object, each integer takes the same amount of time to add as the last. The following program illustrates.

```
import time
import struct
time.clock() # for Windows

def time_list():
    print("adding 9,999,999 0s to one list 9 times:")
    a = []
    for i in range(9):
        start_time = time.clock()
        for j in range(9999999):
            a += [0]
        end_time = time.clock()
        print("loop %d took %f seconds" %(i, end_time - start_time))
    print()

def time_bytes_object():
    print("adding 99,999 pad bytes to a bytes object 9 times:")
    a = bytes()
    for i in range(9):
        start_time = time.clock()
        for j in range(99999):
            a += struct.pack('<B', 0)
        end_time = time.clock()
        print("loop %d took %f seconds" %(i, end_time - start_time))
    print()

time_list()
time_bytes_object()
```

What is it about the bytes object (or the struct.pack function) that makes adding bytes take increasing amounts of time? Or is there a faster way to collect a bunch of bytes than the way used in my example?

Thanks for any help,

Victor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Byte strings (and Unicode strings) in Python are immutable, whereas lists are mutable.

What this means is that every append (`+=`) done on a byte string must make a copy of that string; the original is not modified (though it will be garbage-collected later). In contrast, the `append` method of `list` (also used by `+=`) will actually modify the list.

What you want is the `bytearray` type, which is a mutable type functioning much like a list of bytes. Appending to a `bytearray` takes (amortized) constant time, and it is easily converted to and from a byte string.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the line "a = bytes()" to "a = bytearray()". Putting bytes in a bytearray this time did not slow down as bytes accumulated.

Answer (score 2):

A `bytes` object is immutable just like a string. Every time you do `a += something`, Python is creating a *new* object, copying `a + something` into it, and then assigning it to `a`.

You will be better using the [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray) type which is a [mutable sequence](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) and supports an `append` method.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem as you have, however i have found this isnt an issue in python 2.7.

ie, the same script, that runs over a a 60mb file, reading 3 integers at a time, applying some changes, then appending them to a 'bytes' using my_var += in_bytes takes 100 times longer to run in python 3.3

python 3.3:  172.76 seconds

python 2.7:  1.72519993782

Answer (score 2):

I just want to cover [nneonneos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359270/1149736) in a bit greater depth (I was curious how things work here under the hood).

The main difference is already mentioned in documentation for [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

> Return a new array of bytes. *The bytearray type is a **mutable sequence** of integers* in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as most methods that the bytes type has, see Bytes and Byte Array Methods.

On the other hand [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#bytes) is immutable:

> Return a new “bytes” object, *which is an **immutable sequence*** of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. bytes is an immutable version of bytearray – it has the same non-mutating methods and the same indexing and slicing behavior.

---

You can easily demonstrate this in CPython where [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#id) returns address of the object:

> **CPython implementation detail**: This is the address of the object in memory.

When you extend `bytes()` you always get new object:

```
>>> a = bytes(b'abc')
>>> id(a)
52845824
>>> a += b'de'
>>> id(a)
52843384
```

Whereas `bytearray()` remains the same object with different properties

```
>>> b = bytearray(b'abc')
>>> id(b)
52786352
>>> b += b'de'
>>> id(b)
52786352
```

---

I wanted to see how does this look internally, so [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/dis.html) came in handy:

```
>>> def iadd(a, b):
...     a += b
...     return a
... 
>>> dis.dis(iadd)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 INPLACE_ADD
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

So I figured in the end C routing [`PyNumber_InPlaceAdd`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.2/Objects/abstract.c#L1064) gets called, so lets start gdb.

---

#### Bytes

```
(gdb) b PyNumber_InPlaceAdd
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5317a7: file Objects/abstract.c, line 1066.
(gdb) c
>>> a = b'abc'
>>> a += b'de'

Breakpoint 1, PyNumber_InPlaceAdd (v=0xb030f0, w=0xb03040) at Objects/abstract.c:1066
1066        PyObject *result = binary_iop1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_inplace_add),
(gdb) s
binary_iop1 (v=0xb030f0, w=0xb03040, iop_slot=152, op_slot=0) at Objects/abstract.c:1010
1010        PyNumberMethods *mv = v->ob_type->tp_as_number;
(gdb) s
1011        if (mv != NULL) {
(gdb) info locals
mv = 0x0
(gdb) 
1021        return binary_op1(v, w, op_slot);
(gdb) 
binary_op1 (v=0xb030f0, w=0xb03040, op_slot=0) at Objects/abstract.c:765
            ...
(gdb) 
796     return Py_NotImplemented;
PyNumber_InPlaceAdd (v=0xb030f0, w=0xb03040) at Objects/abstract.c:1068
1068        if (result == Py_NotImplemented) {
(gdb) 
1069            PySequenceMethods *m = v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
(gdb) 
1070            Py_DECREF(result);
(gdb) info locals
m = 0x856940 <bytes_as_sequence>
(gdb) s
1071            if (m != NULL) {
(gdb) 
1072                binaryfunc f = NULL;
(gdb) 
1073                f = m->sq_inplace_concat;
(gdb) 
1074                if (f == NULL)
(gdb) 
1075                    f = m->sq_concat;
(gdb) 
1076                if (f != NULL)
(gdb) 
1077                    return (*f)(v, w);
(gdb) info locals f
f = 0x54948c <bytes_concat>
```

So in the end [`bytes_concat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1264) gets called and memory gets copied:

```
size = va.len + vb.len;
if (size < 0) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    goto done;
}

result = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size);
if (result != NULL) {
    memcpy(PyBytes_AS_STRING(result), va.buf, va.len);
    memcpy(PyBytes_AS_STRING(result) + va.len, vb.buf, vb.len);
}
```

---

#### bytearray

It has similar flow (also ends up in `PyNumber_InPlaceAdd`):

```
>>> b = bytearray(b'abc')
[57107 refs]
>>> b += b'de'

Breakpoint 1, PyNumber_InPlaceAdd (v=0xa35b80, w=0xb03040) at Objects/abstract.c:1066
1066        PyObject *result = binary_iop1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_inplace_add),
(gdb) n
1068        if (result == Py_NotImplemented) {
(gdb) s
1069            PySequenceMethods *m = v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
(gdb) 
1070            Py_DECREF(result);
(gdb) 
1071            if (m != NULL) {
(gdb) 
1072                binaryfunc f = NULL;
(gdb) 
1073                f = m->sq_inplace_concat;
(gdb) 
1074                if (f == NULL)
(gdb) info locals
f = 0x537901 <bytearray_iconcat>
(gdb) n
1076                if (f != NULL)
(gdb) 
1077                    return (*f)(v, w);
```

With `bytes` pointer `m->sq_inplace_concat` was empty, so `m->sq_concat` got called, `bytearray` has it set, so [`bytearray_iconcat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#L315) gets called and ends up in:

```
if (size < self->ob_alloc) {
    Py_SIZE(self) = size;
    PyByteArray_AS_STRING(self)[Py_SIZE(self)] = '\0'; /* Trailing null byte */
}
else if (PyByteArray_Resize((PyObject *)self, size) < 0) {
    PyBuffer_Release(&vo);
    return NULL;
}
memcpy(PyByteArray_AS_STRING(self) + mysize, vo.buf, vo.len);
```

So thus, the speed difference (in my case I've needed to build up one `bytes` from 80000+ chunks and with `bytes` it took 180 seconds, with `bytearray` 0.260).